# Ionic Button content description

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing an ionic 2 app for android/iOS. I need to override the content description of a button when talkback feature is enabled in the device. I tried with alt and name options in button but nothing seems to be working.

```
<button ion-fab color="danger" (click)="share()" name="share" alt="Share" role="presentation">
  <ion-icon name="md-share" ></ion-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to override the default content description I specified the aria-label in button as shown below

```
<button click)="collapseDetails()" aria-label="Collapse">
  <ion-icon [name]="icon_collapse" aria-hidden="true" item-left color="primary">
  </ion-icon>
  {{ displayName }}          
</button>
```

In order to set the aria-label dynamically you can use

```
<ion-label attr.aria-label="{{display_name}} check the box to receive notifications" >{{display_name}} </ion-label>
```

Comment: The first block of code worked for me (using Ionic 3)